# No module QtMultimedia [Mac OS - Anaconda - Python 3.7 - PyQt5]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, anaconda, pyqt5

I would like to play with `QtMultimedia` of `PyQt5` but this does not work.

```
> conda list pyqt
# packages in environment at /anaconda3:
#
# Name       Version       Build  Channel
pyqt         5.9.2         py37h655552a_2
> python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda custom (64-bit) on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5.QtMultimedia
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtMultimedia'
```

This looks like a bug.

Something strange : I have a file `/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/QtMultimediaWidgets.pyi` which imports `QtMultimedia` but no `QtMultimedia.pyi`.

Can I easily fix this and what is the best way to report this bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed this was a bug from conda. I have made recently some updates that fixe my problem.

Comment: I've installed anaconda from strach but this is still the issue. Did they correct the bug, do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pip3 install pyqt5 --user
```

There is probably a conda equivalent, but this works for me in a conda environment without any problems. I presume that there is some permissions issue trying to install it for all users.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed this was a bug from conda. I have made recently some updates that fixe my problem.

Comment: The command "pip install pyqt5 -- user" solved the problem on one of my computers but fundamentally breaks Qt on another. Can be rolled back with "pip uninstall pyqt5" though, so it's worth a try.