# Error: No module named 'PyQt5.QtMultimedia'

Tags: pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I am trying to build a GUI integrating videos, and for this I need to import PyQt5.QtMultimedia. Yet when trying to import the module (import PyQt5.QtMultimedia) I receive an error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtMultimedia'.

I am working on Ubuntu 18.04, and my Python packages come from Anaconda. The "conda list" command reports that pyqt is installed properly, version 5.9.2. All the other PyQt5 imports have worked fine so far, it is really only PyQt5.QtMultimedia that causes issues.

This problem is already discussed in these posts: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52973871/no-module-qtmultimedia-mac-os-anaconda-python-3-7-pyqt5), [link2](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10250), but they do not provide any solution.

I have tried uninstalling (sudo apt-get remove python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia) and re-installing (sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia), without success.

Could someone help? My project is really stuck if I can't fix this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use apt or apt-get then you shouldn't use anaconda python as they are different, you should use system python: `python3 your_script.py`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But any package, whether installed by pip or conda should be usable by Python, no? For instance, I have installed TensorFlow with pip and it works fine, even though I am running on my conda jupyter.

Comment: This being said, I have conda-uninstalled pyqt and re-installed it, without effect. it still installs the same version (5.9.2), which, given the discussions in the posts linked, seems to be responsible for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I managed to solve the problem. Kind of, using brute strength.

There is basically no possible workaround with conda as:

- conda installs its own version of PyQt5 called pyqt, which includes most (but not all) features of PyQt5, version 5.9.2. This version in particular does not have QtMultimedia, hence the error.
- you can't pip install (or regular install) PyQt5 on top of your conda Python. Here it seems to create conflicts and make your whole PyQt setting buggy. To be avoided.

So, the only solution left is not to use Python with conda. I uninstalled conda (certainly not necessary, one may just use base python if installed), and went back to base python. Unfortunately, that also means the packages provided by conda are not available anymore. Still, I managed to install PyQt5 properly, and I can now use QtMultimedia normally.

pros: it works

cons: fix is extreme as it implies giving up using conda altogether

Comment: This page: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment explains that it is still possible to use both conda and pip. Start with a new conda environment, install all conda requirements, and only then install pip requirements. Here you would install whatever you need with conda and only then you would pip PyQt. Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That may work, indeed.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on linux Os just install python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
On Ubuntu or Debian based system install using the command below:

```
sudo apt install python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia
```