# Can't Get List of Cameras in QtMultimedia on Windows Platform

Tags: python, camera, pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I want to display streaming video using QtMultimedia modules in Python on a Windows 10 platform.  However, the first most fundamental step is not working for me – identifying available cameras.

Windows Device Manager confirms that there are two cameras attached to my laptop computer – a webcam and a USB capture device.

My script does not identify any available cameras with the following script:

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCameraInfo
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
import sys

    class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       myList = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()
       print('List = ', myList)
       self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Result:

```
List =  []
```

Is there a fundamental issue with QtMultimedia cameras and Windows 10 that I’m unaware of?

Note: I have successfully used QtMultimedia to display a video read from a file.  Now I want to display from a video stream.

Comment: Is it Windows 10 N? What version of PyQt? Can you try to create an instance of a QApplication before querying the cameras?

Comment: @musicamante - My PyQt is v5.12.13.  I revised my script (above) to add a QApplication instance, but the result was still an empty list

Comment: I can see various reports on a similar problem, often related to different causes. I suggest you to do some research, including the C++ questions (most of the times is just trivial code). You didn't answer about Windows N, btw.

Comment: @musicamante - I'm not using Windows 10 N.  I researched it, but will research it further.

Comment: Anaconda was the issue.  See the solution.

Comment: Good. For future reference, always remember mentioning the full environment: it's generally assumed that the setup uses standard *official* installations (system python or downloaded from the official website, then pip).

Comment: Will do.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61355187/error-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtmultimedia) that Anaconda does not include the full set PtQt5 modules. The solution was to uninstall Anaconda (or Miniconda), install the basic Python and `pip install` all the needed packages. I also downloaded Spyder from PyPI, so very little has changed.

When in Anaconda, [this QCamera example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/creating-a-camera-application-using-pyqt5/) would not execute because of several import errors.  It works flawlessly now after replacing the Anaconda environment with a basic Python environment (and installing the needed packages).